# How can I determine the minimal installation set for a list of packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

I have some installation notes for installing the GLEW libraries for development purposes. They read:

> Install everything with "glew" in its name.

This means I currently run:

```
sudo apt install glew-utils libglewmx-dev libglew-dbg libglewmx-dbg libglew-dev libglewmx1.10 libglew1.10
```

...except that I'm sure some of these are prerequisites, and I don't need to include them in the list.

Given that I have a *list of package names* as above, how can I reduce it to install only the non-dependencies, *without having inspect each package's dependencies individually* in Synaptic Package Manager, `aptitude` or a similar tool?

I guess I'm looking for either a "Select a group of packages" option in a GUI program or

```
magic-debian-tool <LIST-OF-PACKAGES>
```

Comment: Slightly different language, but same answer as the link I gave.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I'm looking for a solution that takes a list of packages as input, rather than inspecting each package one by one - I've updated the question to include a CLI example of what I don't want

Comment: What is wrong with `apt-get install glew` ?

Comment: Voting to reopen because while this can technically be done with `aptitude why` it would be a *lot* of work cross-referencing all the packages to work out the minimal set of packages. For example, I'm installing Chromium using pyppeteer, and right now I'm repeating an install+try to run Chromium loop until I have installed all the dependencies rather than listing all the dependencies (such as bash and libc6) in my Dockerfile.

Comment: @l0b0 I never got around to finishing it, but see if https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369653/70524 helps.